# Navigation in iOS using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

i have an ios app which uses a login page and after authenticating it enters into the inbox page.But after entering the inbox page it comes back automatically to the login page

Login.m

```
{
      if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0)
      {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                            message:@"Make sure you enter a username and password!"
                                                           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
     }
    else
    {
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Login_Info WHERE username='%@'",username]; // Execute the query.
        NSLog(@" query = %@", query );
        // Get the results.
        if (self.arrLogin_Info != nil) {
            self.arrLogin_Info = nil;
        }
        self.arrLogin_Info = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];
        [def setObject:[self.arrLogin_Info objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"idKey"];
        [def setObject:[self.arrLogin_Info objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"usernameKey"];
        [def setObject:[self.arrLogin_Info objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"passwordKey"];
        [def setObject:[self.arrLogin_Info objectAtIndex:3] forKey:@"emailKey"];

        NSLog(@" query output = %@", self.arrLogin_Info);



    NSString *val = [self.arrLogin_Info objectAtIndex:2];

   // NSLog(@" val = %@",val);

        if ([val isEqualToString:password] )
        {
           // NSLog(@" Inside if before entering app");
           [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
             //NSLog(@" Inside else before entering app");

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!"
                                                                message:@"Please ensure you have entered the correct password!"
                                                               delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
  }


@end
```

Inbox.m

```
  -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {


        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        id u = [def objectForKey:@"idkey"];


        if(u)
        {

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select *from Messages where recipient_ID=%@",u];

        self.msg = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

           //  [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

        else
        {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
        }
       // [self.tableView reloadData];

     }


- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    //[PFUser logOut];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin" ])

    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

    }

}
```

Comment: You have only stated what it does. What should it be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Inbox` view controller uses the presence of an object for the key 'idkey' in NSUserDefaults to  determine whether the user is already logged in, or whether to show the login screen.

I presume that this line in login.m

```
 [def setObject:[self.arrLogin_Info objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"idKey"];
```

is supposed to be setting that key, but you don't show where you initialise `def` - so my guess is that this is nil and you aren't saving the data in `NSUserDefaults`.

Also, all of this -

```
 if (self.arrLogin_Info != nil) {
        self.arrLogin_Info = nil;
 }
 self.arrLogin_Info = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];
```

can be simplified to this

```
 self.arrLogin_Info = [self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query];
```

Comment: thanks but that isn't the answer. The soln is to simply comment out the else part in viewWillAppear method of Inbox.m.